# Need help in Unix Shell script

Tags: unix

I am working on a unix script to execute the below task
a) There are total of >100 folders and each folder has a file with the same name (a.txt).
b) Task is to copy a.txt from each folder rename it based on folder name and save the file in newly created folder.
c) In the end all the a1.txt,a2.txt etc.., will be in the new folder

I am trying but not able to succeed...any help will be appreciated

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.